# How to find and replace text spanning multiple nodes in html using C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, html-agility-pack

Consider the html below. The word 'response' has been edited to 'reason', by deleting 'sp' (`<del>`tag) and inserting 'as'  (`<ins>`tag) and deleting 'se' (`<del>`tag)

```
<div >
re
<span class="del" data-userid="11" data-username="user">sp</span>
<span class="ins" data-userid="11" data-username="user">as</span>
on
<span class="del" data-userid="11" data-username="user" >se</span>
</div>
```

I need to find the word **reason** in this html, and be able to replace it with some other word.
How to achieve this? The problem here is

1. being able to avoid the `<del>` tags while finding the word.
2. Find the nodes with text 'reason'
3. Replace those nodes with some other word.

I need a solution in C#/Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Something's like:

`load your html into HtmlDocument object
newDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").FirstOrDefault().ChildNodes.Where(_ => !_.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("del"));`

This will give you every children not including class `del`.

Comment: Thats great, it gives me the whole sentence, but how do I find the nodes having text 'reason'  and replace them with some other word?

Comment: If you call `.InnerText` of the result from above command it will give you 
reason. I am not sure how you want to replace it, you can call `.Remove()` it will remove this element and you can set whatever html you want.

Comment: Thanks Hung. Actually, the div doesn't contain only the word I need to find, it can contain a whole sentence. The innerText of div wouldn't always give me reason, it can contain the word reason.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finally doing it on client side, but find and replacing word across nodes in DOM and then saving it on server.